# getting all permutations for 5 positions with 2 numbers in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have to generate all permutations for 5 positions with 2 numbers in python

ex:
numbers are `0,1`

output:

```
0 0 0 0 0,  
0 0 0 0 1, 
    .
    .
1 1 1 1 1
```

I know this implementation using loops. Is there any built-in function in python to do this or any other simple way.

Answer (score 1):

**itertools.product()**

> This tool computes the cartesian product of input iterables.  It is
>   equivalent to nested for-loops.

For example, product(A, B) returns
the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in B).

```
import itertools
lst = list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=5))
print (lst)
```

output:

```
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1, 1) ...
```

.

```
for item in lst:
    i = ' '.join(str(e) for e in item)
    print ("{},".format(i))
```

output:

```
0 0 0 0 0,
0 0 0 0 1,
0 0 0 1 0,
0 0 0 1 1,
0 0 1 0 0,
0 0 1 0 1,
0 0 1 1 0,
0 0 1 1 1,
0 1 0 0 0,
0 1 0 0 1,
0 1 0 1 0,
 . . .
```